# Can't add some code into my point counter script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, unity3d-2dtools

I have this script that is currently working fine, and I want to add some extra code so that if I hit an object with a different tag it subtracts 300 points. In other words, here is the script that works well:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class POINTS : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text countText;
    public Text winText;


    private Rigidbody rb;
    private int count;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        count = 0;
        SetCountText();
        winText.text = "";
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up"))
            {
                other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                count = count + 300;
                SetCountText();
            }
    }

    void SetCountText()
    {
        countText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString();
        if (count >= 10000)
        {
            winText.text = "Congrats! To play again press <";
        }
    }
}
```

And I think that this should work (note that I added some code after count = count + 300 so that in theory it should start subtracting points

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class POINTS : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text countText;
    public Text winText;


    private Rigidbody rb;
    private int count;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        count = 0;
        SetCountText();
        winText.text = "";
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up"))
            {
                other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                count = count + 300;
            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("TestSolid"))
            {
                other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                count = count - 300;
                SetCountText();
            }
    }

    void SetCountText()
    {
        countText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString();
        if (count >= 10000)
        {
            winText.text = "Congrats! To play again press <";
        }
    }
}
```

But if I try to run that it says that SetCountText hasn't been declared. How do I get this to work? I am very new to scripting so sorry if this is a stupid question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing bracket is missing. I think you should learn how to read compiler output.

Comment: Thanks for that, now it works without any errors. However, it actually counts only the Pick Up points, and none of the TestSolid points show up on the counter. Why? I've tagged everything, and if I set everything to Pick Up it counts perfectly! Why is it counting only the first tag?

Comment: Ok. I think we are missing so much here. Let's start with where this behaviour is attached to?

Comment: Script that is attached to the pick ups and canvas. Would you want a OneDrive link so you could see my project yourself?

Comment: That code is part of a script I have attached to the Player, Canvas, Count Text and Win Text. As I said I have tagged the 2 pick ups well.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if you analysed how this behaviour is attached to other parts of your system. Because it looks like you store count property in behaviour class which for example can be just a temporary object to perform some custom actions, not to store values. So maybe you need to add count property to your main game object or somewhere like that and change it's value in behaviour.

Comment: I added the counter script to the player controller script, and now it doesn't show any errors. However, I have it so the player goes thru the Pick Up 1st, and then the TestSolid. The points for Pick Up show up, but then the player goes straight thru TestSolid without even picking it up! It literally doesn't even know that the TestSolid exists. Total bummer for me. BTW where can I change it's value in "behavior"? I'm in Unity almost 2 weeks so IDK where can I find behavior sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It's rather painful to say something meaningful in comments so i will put it as answer. 
I am not into Unity very much but it looks like the place where you store Count property may be not the best. It looks like as you are extending class named behaviour it can be for example a temporary object created each time when some event happens on canvas. What I mean is that you have to know the platform. Read the spec. 
What can solve your question would be storing Count in some more appropriate place. I.e. in a main game object (if I correctly understand the meaning of what you refer to as Count)
The code would look like:

```
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("TestSolid"))             
{                 
    other.gameObject.SetActive(false);                 
    Game.Count -= Settings.HitSolidDamage;                 
    SetCountText();
}
```